# Android: Proper coding of getCacheDir()

Tags: android

I am researching on how to get the cache file size and directory of every application that is installed in my android phone programmatically, based on what I found on my research, I need to use **getCacheDir()**, my question is, what is the proper coding using **getCacheDir()** ?
can someone give me an example how to use it? I'm new to android so I'm not familiar yet on the proper coding in android

Answer (score 1):

You can't without rooting.  getCacheDir returns an app specific directory.  Like internal storage, its not possible to access this directory from any other app.  This is for security purposes, without this apps could gain access to data they shouldn't-  for example you could read password protected websites if the html was cached.

Comment: but is there a way to get the cache file size of application in my android phone?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) `getCacheDir()` Returns the absolute path to the **application specific** cache directory on the filesystem.

It will return a path like

> /data/data/yourapp/cache/

So the point is that getCacheDir will return cache path for your application only, not for every application!

Of course you can try replacing package names if you know the package name of every other application.

**Note** that these are Internal caches and you will get only file access to your application's Cache file not to other applications cache file.

If you are looking for External caches use  `getExternalCacheDir()` it will return a path from sdcard(External Storage)

Comment: I have a program that can retrieve the package name of every application in my mobile, do you have a sample where I should replace the package name? I don't have a intention to access the cache file of application, I just want to get it's directory and file size..

Comment: you can get the file path by replacing the package name .. but i dont think you can get the file size..